# Alternating table row color with the first row a different color

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table where the header is green and then the rows alternate between different styles.

How can I style the first row's color as well as having the others alternate?

My HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" class="butikHeader">
        <tr>
            <td>Tilføj</td>
            <td>Stk</td>
            <td>Produkt navn</td>
            <td>Pris</td>
            <td>Mere info</td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="CheckboxValue" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width: 50px;" class="AntalBoxInput" value="<%# Eval("Antal") %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td><%# Eval("navn") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("pris") %> Kr,-</td>
                    <td><a href="produkt.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>">Info</a></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```

My CSS:

```
    .butikHeader tr:first-child {
    background:#8AB512;
    color:#FFF;
}
.butikHeader tr:nth-child(even) {
    background:#FFF;
    border:0px;
    color:#000;
}
.butikHeader tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#DFE7C0;
}
```

I would like to make it look like something like [this](http://billedeupload.dk/?v=M5iso.png) or [this](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

Comment: Just set the required class in each table row, like <tr class="first-child"> etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to place the `first-child` rule after the rest, so it overrides them.

```
.butikHeader tr:nth-child(even) {
    background:#FFF;
    border:0px;
    color:#000;
}
.butikHeader tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#DFE7C0;
}
.butikHeader tr:first-child {
    background:#8AB512;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: It makes such a small Meldrum in between, what can it kicks ?, I've tried with `border` and it does not work

Comment: Try to add `border-spacing: 0;` to the table CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use `thead` and `tbody`

```css
thead tr {
  background:#8AB512;
    color:#FFF;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background:#FFF;
    border:0px;
    color:#000;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#DFE7C0;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Errrm your code all works. I'd guess something that's not in your sample code is affecting it.

Try adding !important after each css statement eg:

```
.butikHeader tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#DFE7C0 !important;
}
```

To test the theory. I'm not a fan of using !important generally by the way, but that's another story.

Also I would suggest you split your top row into a thead element and subsequent ones into a tbody statement, but I guess again, that's another story.