# Create CSS for first table row, alternate others

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a table that is generated from another application/service that I am not able to modify the layout of. I would like to have CSS where the first row has a style, and then the other rows have alternating styles. The major issue is that there are no differences in the html concerning the header and other rows.

```
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>Firstname</th>
    <td>Lastname</th> 
    <td>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've seen things in CSS like `table > tr:n-child(odd)` but those don't work.  Is there a way for me to say "tr:nth-child(ODD EXCEPT WHEN = 1)" ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is a snapshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

This was the solution I settled on. The key was to put the `first-child` selector after the `nth-child(2n + 1)` selector so the header style would override the iterative style. I might look into the `:not` selector, but I wanted to get rolling again.

```css
div#tablewrappingdiv> table > tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td{
    background-color: #eee;
}
div#tablewrappingdiv> table > tbody > tr:first-child > td{
    background-color: #006c00;
}           
div#tablewrappingdiv> table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n + 2) > td{
    background-color: #d8e4bc;
}
```

Comment: "I would like to have CSS where the first row has a style, and then the other rows have alternating styles" So what, specifically, is stopping you from achieving this? Typically when people ask for help here they show what they've tried. Please include some CSS; you've indicated you've tried some things but they don't quite work... if we see it, we can help make it work. But we won't likely write it from scratch for you.

Comment: @TylerH I wasn't asking for something to be written from scratch, I was asking for direction."How do I get there" is different from "Carry me there".

Comment: And directions are most useful when you can provide some information on your starting point. If I am telling you how to get to the Eiffel Tower I need to know whether you are starting in Spartanburg or Paris, for example. And, as the Paris Tourist Center, we'd rather not provide you with details on how to get out of your neighborhood and to the local airport if you can manage that on your own.

Comment: Do remember the downfalls for the solution you have picked though, if you add many style properties to your 2n+1 tr, you'll have to override them all by changing their values in the first-child to make it look different even if you don't want any style applied at all on it. And it all could be avoided by just adding :not(:first-child) to it.

Comment: @FlexFiend I made a mistake with the offsets of the rules at first (got confused about 0-based vs. 1-based index). Do not use `+1` and `+2`, but rather `+2` and `+3`. This will let the row coloring only start **after** the header and the order of rules does not matter anymore. I corrected my answer accordingly. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8xhs0h1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Selector Reference for `nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):

```
tr:first-child     {darkgreen}  (nth-child(0) would also work)
tr:nth-child(2n+2) {white}
tr:nth-child(2n+3) {lightgreen}
```

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is
>   a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/z8xhs0h1/

---

For this rather simple case (even/odd, first different), take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378758/7653073). It is slightly easier to read and says that you just have to put the `first-child` rule last:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {white}
tr:nth-child(odd)  {lightgreen}
tr:first-child     {darkgreen}  (overrides white color)
```

Still, for more complicated cases or in case you want to be very explicit, the `an+b` rules can be quite flexible.

Comment: Just a tip to note, if you're going to use even/odd selectors, its better not to try and override the odd selector by placing the first child later. You'll have to mention each and every attribute for the property to make it look different than the odd selectors attribute, rather you should try something like my solution for that scenario.

Comment: Good point. I generally prefer not overriding properties, too. Though sometimes, this overriding can increase readability, for example if you only want to change a few properties but leave a majority untouched. Finding the best/easiest/most maintainable solution for the specific case is key, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You could also make use of something like this.

- We need to alternative the even and odd rows, using the `nth-child(even/odd)` selectors is pretty appropriate here.
- And since we want to `exclude the first row` (*which is an odd number*) you can just use the `:not(:first-child) selector with the odd attribute`.

```css
#t01 tr:first-child{
background:yellow;
}
#t01 tr:nth-child(even){
background:red;
}
#t01 tr:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child){
background:green;
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Lastname</td> 
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr:first-child`, `tr:nth-child(2n+2)` and `tr:nth-child(2n+3)` as shown below, where "nth-child(2n+3)" means "every second child starting from the third one":

```css
tr:first-child {
  background: #fa0;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background: #a0f;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background: #0eb;
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```